# JavaFX 2.2 JFXPanel in Swing application showing Swing modal dialogs

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I have a well established Swing application that I'm partially upgrading to JavaFX using JFXPanel. The JFrame with the JFXPanel gets a scene from another class which creates a root node in code (not FXML) that is an HBox with a pretty simple left-hand sidebar with dynamically generated links and buttons and stuff and a right-hand side that is dynamically filled in with content based on the button a user presses on the left side. The right-side content is built with several sets of FXML and controller classes.

Within each of these right-side content classes, I have to bring up some standard Swing JDialogs or JOptionPane's that accept a parent (JFrame or JDialog) in the constructor for screen placement and modality. (These JDialogs and JOptionPanes come from a library of common components that we have written over the years)

Is there a way at runtime for me to get a reference to the JFrame containing the JFXPanel so I can instantiate them with proper modality?

** EDIT **

1. Modality actually works
2. What I really want to do now is center the dialog over the parent. Of course, I'm sure that this will be useful for a myriad of other reasons for me in the future.
3. Here is an abbreviated version. I have been able to run it, so it should work for you.
4. I apologize if this is a bit messy :-S
5. Thanks a ton for your assistance!

This is the main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingMain extends JFrame {

    public static final String TITLE = "Main JFrame";

    private GridBagLayout gridBagLayout1 = new GridBagLayout();

    private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    private JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private JFXSceneMaker sceneMaker = new JFXSceneMaker(this);

    public SwingMain() {
        super();
        try {
            init();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SwingMain swingMainTest = new SwingMain();
        swingMainTest.setVisible(true);
    }

    void init() throws Exception {
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(1280, 864);
        this.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        this.setPreferredSize(minimumSize);
        jPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout1);
        this.setTitle(TITLE);

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        try {
            prepareScene();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log error
        }

        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        jPanel.add(jfxPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(
                        0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    }

    protected void prepareScene() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Scene scene = sceneMaker.getScene();
                    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    // log error
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the class that provides the scene for the JFXPanel

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class JFXSceneMaker {
    private static final Interpolator interpolator = Interpolator.SPLINE(0.4829, 0.5709, 0.6803, 0.9928);

    // To obtain a scalable page layout, you define all positions and sizes in terms of “root em” (rem), 
    //  the em size of the default font
    private final double rem = Math.rint(new Text("").getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
    private double SIDEBAR_WIDTH = rem * 13;
    private Pane root;
    private StackPane currentPane, sparePane;
    private VBox sideBar;
    private int currentPaneIndex = 0;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private ContentPane nextPane = null;
    private int nextPaneIndex;
    private JFrame swingParent;

    public static final String TITLE = "JavaFX Rocks!";

    private ContentPane[] panes;

    public JFXSceneMaker(JFrame frame) {
        // This is a reference to the Swing parent JFrame that I want to place the JOptionPanes and JDialogs over
        this.swingParent = frame;
    }

    public Scene getScene() throws IOException {

        Parent pane1 = FXMLLoader.load(Pane1Controller.class.getResource("pane1contentPane.fxml"));
        Parent pane2 = FXMLLoader.load(Pane2Controller.class.getResource("pane2contentPane.fxml"));
        Parent pane3 = FXMLLoader.load(Pane3Controller.class.getResource("pane3contentPane.fxml"));

        panes = new ContentPane[]{
            new ContentPane("Panel1", pane1),
            new ContentPane("Panel2", pane2),
            new ContentPane("Panel3", pane3)
        };

        // create the left-hand side bar
        sideBar = new VBox(0);
        sideBar.setId("SideBar");
        sideBar.setPrefWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
        sideBar.setMinWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
        sideBar.setMaxWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
        sideBar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #25282c");
        HBox.setHgrow(sideBar, Priority.NEVER);

        PersistentButtonToggleGroup toggleGroup = new PersistentButtonToggleGroup();
        for (int i=0; i < panes.length; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            final ContentPane contentPane = panes[i];
            final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(contentPane.getName());
            if (i==0) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        button.setSelected(true);
                        button.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
            button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            button.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
            button.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    switchcontentPane(contentPane, index);
                }
            });
            sideBar.getChildren().add(button);
        }

        // current Pane and sparePane are used for switching between panes
        currentPane = new StackPane();
        currentPane.getChildren().setAll(panes[0].getContent());

        sparePane = new StackPane();
        sparePane.setVisible(false);

        // contentPanePane is the right side of the scene where the relevant content is displayed
        StackPane contentPanePane = new StackPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(contentPanePane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        contentPanePane.getChildren().addAll(currentPane, sparePane);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(currentPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(currentPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(currentPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(currentPane, 0.0);

        //create root node
        root = new HBox();
        root.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        root.setPrefSize(1250, 844);

        root.getChildren().addAll(sideBar,contentPanePane);

        return SceneBuilder.create()
                .root(root)
                .build();
    }

    public void switchcontentPane(ContentPane newcontentPane, final int contentPaneIndex) {
        // check if existing animation running
        if (timeline != null) {
            nextPane = newcontentPane;
            nextPaneIndex = contentPaneIndex;
            timeline.setRate(4);
            return;
        } else {
            nextPane = null;
            nextPaneIndex = -1;
        }
        // load new content
        sparePane.getChildren().setAll(newcontentPane.getContent());
        sparePane.setCache(true);
        currentPane.setCache(true);
        // wait one pulse then animate
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                // animate switch
                if (contentPaneIndex > currentPaneIndex) { // animate from bottom
                    currentPaneIndex = contentPaneIndex;
                    sparePane.setTranslateY(root.getHeight());
                    sparePane.setVisible(true);
                    timeline = TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), 
                                    new KeyValue(currentPane.translateYProperty(),0,interpolator),
                                    new KeyValue(sparePane.translateYProperty(),root.getHeight(),interpolator)
                                ),
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800), 
                                    animationEndEventHandler,
                                    new KeyValue(currentPane.translateYProperty(),-root.getHeight(),interpolator),
                                    new KeyValue(sparePane.translateYProperty(),0,interpolator)
                                )
                            )
                            .build();
                    timeline.play();
                } else { // from top
                    currentPaneIndex = contentPaneIndex;
                    sparePane.setTranslateY(-root.getHeight());
                    sparePane.setVisible(true);
                    timeline = TimelineBuilder.create()
                            .keyFrames(
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), 
                                    new KeyValue(currentPane.translateYProperty(),0,interpolator),
                                    new KeyValue(sparePane.translateYProperty(),-root.getHeight(),interpolator)
                                ),
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800), 
                                    animationEndEventHandler,
                                    new KeyValue(currentPane.translateYProperty(),root.getHeight(),interpolator),
                                    new KeyValue(sparePane.translateYProperty(),0,interpolator)
                                )
                            )
                            .build();
                    timeline.play();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> animationEndEventHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            // switch panes
            StackPane temp = currentPane;
            currentPane = sparePane;
            sparePane = temp;
            // cleanup
            timeline = null;
            currentPane.setTranslateY(0);
            sparePane.setCache(false);
            currentPane.setCache(false);
            sparePane.setVisible(false);
            sparePane.getChildren().clear();
            // start any animations
            // check if we have a animation waiting
            if (nextPane != null) {
                switchcontentPane(nextPane, nextPaneIndex);
            }
        }
    };

    public static class PersistentButtonToggleGroup extends ToggleGroup {
        PersistentButtonToggleGroup() {
            super();
            getToggles().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Toggle>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends Toggle> c) {
                    while (c.next())
                        for (final Toggle addedToggle : c.getAddedSubList())
                            ((ToggleButton) addedToggle).addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
                                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                                            if (addedToggle.equals(getSelectedToggle()))
                                                mouseEvent.consume();
                                        }
                                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that will contain the content for the right side panes

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class ContentPane {
    private String name;
    private Parent content;
    protected JFrame swingParent;

    public ContentPane(String name, Parent content) {
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Parent getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

This is the fxml for the first content pane

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="content" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Pane1Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
            <children>
                <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="48.0" style="-fx-font-size: 24; -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6; -fx-background-color: #0072bc; -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 12;" text="Pane 1" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

                </Label>
                <AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                    <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="125.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="optionButton1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show a JOptionPane" />
                            </children>
                        </StackPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the controller for the first pane

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Pane1Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button optionButton1;

    private JFrame swingParent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        optionButton1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                showJOptionPane();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showJOptionPane() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(swingParent, "So...now what?");
    }

}
```

Second pane fxml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="content" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="161.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Pane2Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
            <children>
                <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="48.0" style="-fx-font-size: 24; -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6; -fx-background-color: #0072bc; -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 12;" text="Pane 2" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

                </Label>
                <AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                    <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="125.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="optionButton2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show another JOptionPane" />
                            </children>
                        </StackPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Second pane controller...

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Pane2Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button optionButton2;

    private JFrame swingParent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        optionButton2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                showJOptionPane();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showJOptionPane() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(swingParent, "Here we go again.");
    }

}
```

Third pane fxml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="content" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="161.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Pane3Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
            <children>
                <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="48.0" style="-fx-font-size: 24; -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6; -fx-background-color: #0072bc; -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 12;" text="Pane 3" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

                </Label>
                <AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                    <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="125.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="optionButton3" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show yet another JOptionPane" />
                            </children>
                        </StackPane>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

3rd controller...

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Pane3Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button optionButton3;

    private JFrame swingParent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        optionButton3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                showJOptionPane();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showJOptionPane() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(swingParent, "Here we go again.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) extends [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), therefore you should be able to get a runtime reference to the `JFrame` the same way you would using any Swing component.  I'm assuming you're using something like [`getRootPane(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getRootPane%28%29).

As an alternative to getting a runtime reference, you could always create your own class extending `JFXPanel` and pass in a reference to the `JFrame` in your custom constructor.

**Edit**

If you make your `SwingMain` class into a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), you should be able to easily get a references to any of it's fields.  Here's a demo of how you could use it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingJFXCombo {

    /**
     * The control who starts everything.
     * This should have the references you need.
     * Uses the singleton pattern
     */
    public static class MainController{

        //Top level fields we may need access too
        JFXPanel jfxPanel;
        JPanel jp;
        JFrame frame;

        //Doing singleton stuff
        private static MainController instance;
        public static MainController getInstance(){
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new MainController();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private MainController(){
            jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            jp = new JPanel();

            jp.add(jfxPanel);
            jp.setVisible(true);
            jp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

            //Setup to display swing stuff
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(jp);
            frame.pack();
        }

        public static void initialize(){
            getInstance();

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainController mc = getInstance();
                    Scene scene = mc.initScene();
                    mc.jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
                }
            });
        }

        private Scene initScene(){
            Group  root  =  new  Group();
            Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);
            Text  text  =  new  Text(40,100,"JavaFX Scene");
            text.setFont(new Font(25));
            root.getChildren().add(text);
            return (scene);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Another random class for demonstration purposes
     * This would be similar to your FX Controllers
     */
    public static class RandomController{
        public void printFrameColor(){
            //Now from anywhere, I can get any of the top level items by calling the singleton
            System.out.println(MainController.getInstance().frame.getBackground());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainController.initialize();
        new RandomController().printFrameColor();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although, it's a bit more complicated than that. Actually, the class that creates the scene for the JFXPanel has a reference to the JFrame passed in on the constructor. 

The issue I have is getting that reference to the dynamic contents on the right. They are all instantiated as Parents from FXMLLoader, and I can't find a good way to pass the reference (I've tried creating an interface and passing a constructor parameter). Since they are created generically, the interface does me no good.

Comment: @RonSiven Perhaps if you could provide a simplified version of the problem you're running into, I could help better.  I can make something up, but it likely won't be tailored to your situation any better than my original attempt.

Comment: I have added a working example in the original question. I hope it effectively gets the point across. Thanks again!

Comment: @RonSiven I've updated my answer.  This should get you on the right track.  Your example was a little long (9 files), so I didn't get to loading it up, but seeing the gist of what you're doing does help.

Comment: I finally got back to this problem, and implementing the parent as a singleton did indeed solve the problem. It also has the side affect of making the application more robust, in this case. There should ever be only one of them  at a time presented to the user. So, thanks again!